# How do I restart my factorial calculator so the user can find the factorial of multiple numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compute the factorial of any integer between 0 and 25 using a while loop.

My factorial is outputted correctly, but I want to restart the code so the user can use my program again if they'd like to find the factorial of another number between 1 and 25.

To do this, I made a variable named "stop" so I could use it to stop the program if stop="y".

I set stop="n" so that the while loop can execute once.

After the factorial is calculated, I wanted the user to be asked "Are you done? Type y if you are"

If they press any letter other than y, I would like the while loop to restart. If they press y, I would like the program to end.

```
Stop= “n”
if stop != “y”:
num=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 25:"))

if num >25 or num < 0:
print("Can you please enter a number between 0 and 26?")
    factorial=1;
    while(num>0 and num<=25):
    factorial= factorial*num
    num=num-1
    print("The factorial of your number is:")
    print(factorial)
        stop= str(input(“Are you done? Type y if you are”
print(“Thanks for playing!”)
```

my current output is a syntax error on print("thanks for playing!"). I'm using IDLE (Python 3.8, 32-bit);

Comment: You forgot to close the parentheses in `str(input(“Are you done? Type y if you are”`

Comment: The indentation of your code looks broken.

Comment: And `Stop` is not the same as `stop`.

Comment: I changed stop and fixed the indentation. I still get the syntax error in IDLE.

Comment: I also added the ")" in str(input("are you done?))

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem may be that the quotes around “Thanks for playing!” are different than those around "Enter a number between 1 and 25:" (” is not the same as ", I'm assuming the first was copied from somewhere?).

And careful about your formatting in python; as is, there is nothing indented after your while statement so nothing will run. I believe what you are trying to do is:

```
stop= "n"

while stop != "y":
  num=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 25:"))

  if num > 25 or num < 0:
    print("Can you please enter a number between 0 and 26?")
    continue

  factorial = 1

  while(num>0 and num<=25):
    factorial = factorial*num
    num=num-1
  print("The factorial of your number is: ", factorial)
  stop = str(input("Are you done? Type y if you are"))

print("Thanks for playing!")
```

Comment: When I ran your code. I got an infinite loop at "num=int(input("Enter a number between 1 and 25:")). I got that in my own code when I used "While" so I changed it to "if".

Comment: Then, when I ran the edited code, I got an error on Continue saying "continue not properly in loop"

Comment: The while loop problem may be coming from indentation again. In your original question, because the rest of your code is at the same indentation level as the while loop, the only code that runs is assigning a value to num, never changing stop, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: Continue can only be used in "for" and "while" loops, and therefore if you are using "if" instead of "while", you will get the error you mentioned.

Comment: Even if I changed it it doesn't take away the error

Comment: Are you sure it looks the same? I only ask because [running it online](https://repl.it/repls/StylishIrritatingDeal) works for me.